# Converting javascript webapp to device app using phonegap - but still upload to server DB

Tags: javascript, php, ios, mysql, cordova

I have a working javascript webapp on my server, which allows us to load our research images, tag them and then save them with tagging metadata.  We use php and mysql to save each session to our employee's accounts.

We wish to use PhoneGap to utilize iOS and Android devices running the same app on a portable device in the field. Rather than save locally we still want to utilize the remote storing of image/metadata on the same online database.

- My question is, how to restructure our php/mysql calls to allow for this?

Currently our server based app uses a 'connect.php' file to access the db, then a series of .php files to perform various functions as called by the javascript.

ie:  load.php, save.php, signing.php, imageUpload.php, etc.

Here's the connect.php code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

?>
```

And here is a save.php file we call from the javascript:

```
<?php

require 'connect.php';

        session_start();

if(isset($_REQUEST["jsonString"]) && isset($_REQUEST["user"])){
    $user = $_REQUEST["user"];
    $jsonString = $_REQUEST["jsonString"];
}

if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] == $user) {


    //$sql = "INSERT INTO savetable (user, savestring) VALUES ('Doe', '".$jsonString."')";
$sql = "UPDATE savetable SET `savestring` = '$jsonString' WHERE `user` ='$user'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "This data saved successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

}else{
    echo "Please login.";
}


require 'disconnect.php';
?>
```

I'm able to run all functions of the app from a device using phonegap, but am hung up when it come to calling the php files to access the remote server.

Thank you

Comment: Can't you just make an ajax calls to the <url><filename>.php files?

Comment: at risk of sounding like a complete idiot, how would I do that?

Comment: Sample jQuery call, replace 'data' with your webView's session information... $.ajax({
                   url: 'http://yourdomain/registration.php',
                   type: 'POST',
                   contentType: "application/json",
                   dataType: 'json',
                   data: JSON.stringify(data),
                   timeout: 10000,
                   success: function(result) {
                   console.log("result = " + result);
                   },
                   error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                   }
            });